# webdriver hangs on closing iframe popup

Tags: java, html, iframe, selenium, webdriver

I have a page where a popup is created through iFrames.

- I use switchTo().frame("LookupWindow") to switch to the popup.
- I then successfully enter some text and look up a value
- Once the value is found, I click on on it (still on the popup)
- The popup now closes (because I clicked on the value in the popup)

This all expected behavior and works fine.  However, the code hangs after the statement that clicks the value (which in turn closes the window).  It waits forever, does not report an error at all.

Ideas?  Workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use

switchTo().window("LookupWindow") to switch the control to pop-up window.

After it got closed, you need to switch back to main/previous window using below command.

```
driver.switchTo.defaultContent();
```

See this [post](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-switch-control-to-pop-up-window.html) to know more about how to switch controls between windows.

Comment: The popup is not a window, but a frame, so switchTo().window will not work.  I know I am supposed to go back to the default content with switchTo().defaultcontent().  However, currently, the code hangs before that statement; it hangs right after it executes the last statement within the popup